# Which PowerShell versions

Tags: powershell, windows-10, version, upgrade, winget

Different commands tell me I have different versions of PowerShell.  (1) Why?  (2) Do I need to care?

Following some of the advice here and on other sites I used WinGet to install a later version of PowerShell.  Or so I thought.

Every time I start PowerShell I get a header saying 'Try the cross platform version at ....'  I thought I had done that before but tried again.  Several methods offered so I tried winget for 7.1 version.

Before starting $PSVersionTable.PSVersion said I had 5.1.  Winget ran for a while and then said I had to uninstall previous version.  Deep breath and then I used winget uninstall microsoft.powershell.  Appeared to run smoothly.  Then reran install.

Also appeared to run smoothly and reported success.  I closed PowerShell and restarted.  Still get the 'Try the crossplatform ...' message.  $PSVersionTable.PSVersion still reports 5.1.  As does Get-Host.  But pwsh --version  says 7.3.6

What do I really have?  And, as with so many upgrades, does it really make any difference?

Answer (score 3):

**PowerShell 5.1** is also known as **Windows PowerShell** which is the older **Windows-only** version and is launched via `powershell.exe`.

The modern [open-source](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) **cross-platform** version is **PowerShell 7.x** (also called **PowerShell Core 7.x** as it's built on top of [dotnet core](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download)) which is launched via `pwsh.exe` and can exist side-by-side with Windows PowerShell on Windows-based computers.

You'll get reports of either version depending on how you access it - e.g. launching `powershell.exe` or `pwsh.exe` on the command line.

Both versions are also integrated into various other software products so you'll get information about the underlying version if you query it - e.g. the older **[PowerShell ISE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-7.3)** embeds Windows PowerShell, whereas the **[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)** PowerShell console uses 7.x, etc.

The two products are *mostly* compatible, but there are a fair number of breaking changes. If you want a more in-depth discussion of the specifics you can take a look at:

- [Differences between Windows PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7.x](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/differences-from-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: Thank you.  Very helpful.  I have a related (I think) but different issue so I will start another question.  Title "Powershell scripts won't run since update to 7."